# Able to Edit Removed Posts in Chat

Tags: bug, edits, chat

I noticed that, in the SE chat, if you removed a post, that it could still be edited (by navigating to it using the up arrow), and would show for a second before becoming `(removed)` again. Is this a `bug`, or something `status-bydesign`?

Pic:
[image: Bug]

Note: this is only able to happen if you use the up arrow key to edit, as the edit button disappears when the post is removed.